# how to align 4 checkboxes in a row and continue on a new line?

Tags: php, html

I'm having a problem to align four checkboxes in each row with the code below. Any solution?

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <label  for="form-id"  class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label">그룹</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                        <?php foreach ( $memberGroupList as $memberGroup ) { ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <?php if (in_array($memberGroup->getId(),$arrMemberMemberGroup)) { ?>
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="memberGroupId[]" value="<?php echo $memberGroup->getId()?>" checked > <?php echo $memberGroup->getName()?>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="memberGroupId[]" value="<?php echo $memberGroup->getId()?>"  > <?php echo $memberGroup->getName()?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do this with some small changes to your CSS. Assuming that the class `col-lg-4` is the smallest enclosing `<div>`, you can use `float:left` to align them all on a single row, then use `nth-of-type()` to
add a `clear:left` where you want to start the next row.

In the snippet below, `nth-of-type(4n+1)` is used to select the 5th, 9th, 13th elements and `clear:left` to start a new row.

```css
.col-lg-4 {
            float:left;
        }
        .col-lg-4:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
            clear:left;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-4"><input type="checkbox" value="1" checked> Box 1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"><input type="checkbox" value="2" > Box 2</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"><input type="checkbox" value="3" > Box 3</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4"><input type="checkbox" value="4" > Box 4</div>
                <div class="col-lg-4"><input type="checkbox" value="5" > Box 5</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4"><input type="checkbox" value="6" checked> Box 6</div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4"><input type="checkbox" value="7" > Box 7</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"><input type="checkbox" value="8" > Box 8</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"><input type="checkbox" value="9" > Box 9</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"><input type="checkbox" value="10" > Box 10</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"><input type="checkbox" value="11" > Box 11</div>


</div>
```